# SVN Hudson JIRA interaction

Tags: svn, hudson, jira

I am using the jira plugin on my hudson server. When committing code to svn, my commit comments are included on my jira issue, but it is there any way that the comments can be attributed to the actual person who did the commit instead of having one global jira user for all the hudson generated comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible since the Hudson server would have to serve the credentials of the person checking in. You could probably take a look at the plugin source, but my guess is that even if you had the same user database/LDAP-database for both Subversion and Jira, the process running the Hudson server probably can't login with the given users credential.

Agree that it would be a nice feature.

Comment: That is true, but hudson already stores details for people, you can also administer these users like change their email addresses. I can't see any reason why you couldn't just add jira username and password as extra fields.